# Where does ZSNES save the quicksaves

Tags: 11.10, zsnes

I downloaded ZSNES and did a quicksave but I am moving to another PC. Where does ZSNES by default store the quicksave files. I can't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.zsnes/` should have your configuration and all your quick saves.

Comment: phew!. I thought I had to start all over again. Thanks Bruno!

Comment: Welcome man ;)!